# Enabling plugin failed because MySQL user do not have CREATE permissions

Tags: plugins, mysql, options

Has anyone else had this problem? I'm trying to enable SearchWP plugin (but i don't think this is that specific plugin problem, but maybe my settings?) but it gives me the following error:

> Please ensure the applicable MySQL user has CREATE permissions and try
>   activating again.

What should I do? I tried to google a bit my I wasn't able to find any similar problem. Does it mean I need to change mysql user?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message kinda explains itself. The plugin probably want to create some tables but your woedpress user, the one indicated in `wp-config.php`, do not have a table create permissions. You will have to go into your MySQL administration panels and give the user the create permission as well.